# Can't find wireless printer when connected via ethernet cable but can find it when using wifi?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, printer

I have a brother printer that I can access fine on my laptop when I'm connected to the router via wifi, but once I connect via ethernet cable directly on the same router, it can't find the printer. So I always have to disconnect the ethernet whenever I need to print something.

Is there a way to fix this or is this really just how wireless printers work?

Comment: No, that's not how wireless printers work, that's how your router is configured (probably).

Comment: I agree with the above.  Have you reset the network settings on the printer to see if that makes any difference?  One way to solve your problem is to give the printer a static IP on your network. I do this. The printer is never lost.

Comment: ... but if you have wireless isolation set at the router the above won't change it. Please check your router settings.